# trigger.io tabbar tint inactive

Tags: colors, icons, tabbar, trigger.io

I have an app that uses the tabbar but I don't see a way to change the tint of inactive items. I would like to be able to darken the inactive tabbar icons because my tabbar is a light color, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The tinting options for the tabbar are based on the functionality iOS provides, which is fairly limited. You can set the tint for the bar, which both the active and inactive tabs will be based on, and the colour for the icons/text.

The active tabbar item appears lighter than inactive, so to get the effect you want you may just need to darken the overall tint of your tabbar.